# ESlint и борьба с firebase

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, eslint

Имеется вот так код:
файл: `init.js`

```
var config = {
  apiKey: 'AIzaSyDe-XMpJOsYURFt5HJwrsYgQTqwQ5kGHWg',
  authDomain: 'udemy-ninja-chat-e44dd.firebaseapp.com',
  databaseURL: 'https://udemy-ninja-chat-e44dd.firebaseio.com',
  projectId: 'udemy-ninja-chat-e44dd',
  storageBucket: 'udemy-ninja-chat-e44dd.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: '379210644447'
}
firebase.initializeApp(config)
firebaseApp.firestore().settings({timestampsInSnapshots: true})

export default firebaseApp.firestore()
```

При создании облачной базы данных Firebase мне было предложено вот этот скрипт поместить в моё веб приложение. НО ругается `ESlint`, я починил 80% этого кода, но вот эти строчки всё равно подсвечивает красным:

```
firebase.initializeApp(config)
firebaseApp.firestore().settings({timestampsInSnapshots: true})

export default firebaseApp.firestore()
```

Прочитал по докам и решил в файле .`eslintrc.js` установить правило, которое мне выдавало ESlint: 
`'no-undef': 'off'.` Подчёркивания ушли, но теперь я получаю не своё окно чата, как видел до этого, а просто белый экран в браузере, а когда комментирую выше код в файле `init.js` всё работает, но тогда не работает firebase естественно. Не знаю уже что делать.

Comment: _я получаю не своё окно чата, как видел до этого, а просто белый экран в браузере_ - смотри ошибки в консоли браузера

Comment: подключен ли скрипт с firebase?

Comment: @Grundy на видеоуроке, он просто добавил файл js, закинул туда этот скрип и всё, остальное я тоже самое сделал, 2 раза перепроверил. Он его нигде не подключал

Comment: Думаю, скрипт всеже нужно подключить. https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван, что за видео урок?

Comment: @Grundy на udemy

Comment: @eustatos подключил в компоненте под названием NewMessage потому что делаю чат, но нет, не робит

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван, если это платное, то стоит обратиться к поддержке. Возможно есть материалы по курсу, либо начальное состояние проекта описывается.

Comment: @Grundy, похоже, вот этот https://youtu.be/nWBtU2QNhxk

Comment: @Grundy но там он не до конца, там уже нет того, на чем я застрял :), но я уже справился, спасибо большое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот ссылка на работающее приложение.
[image: Edit ninja-chat]

А это ссылка на репозиторий с курсом.
https://github.com/crea00/vue-firebase/

Comment: Просто лучший братик, спасибо большое!